# Regex Lookahead in Import.io (IF-Else-Then)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, import.io

I'm looking for a regex in import.io crawler script.

The text can either contain:

```
xxx – yyy – zzz
rrr – sss
```

Or

```
xxx
yyy
```

In either case I need the *yyy* part. So I created the following lookahead script:

```
(?=.*\–.*)– ([a-zA-Z0-9]*) –|(\n(.*))
```

And in regex.101 it seems to work okay. [Link to Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hT5sE0/2)

But when I try this regex in import.io, it doesn't seem to work. So does anyone have an idea how to use a proper lookaround in import.io?

(Addition 1:)
It seems that the first test works, so with the dashed. But the second doesn't. Still not sure why.

Comment: You need to match `yyy` or just look it and ignore from match ? Because lookahead are used for latter.

Comment: This regex - `-\s*(\w+)\s*-|\n(\w+)\n(?:\n|$)`- captures any word between hyphens, and any word followed by an empty line **or** end of text. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gK7pN8/1) Is that what you want?

Comment: It seems like it is the newline at fault. That import.io does not handle this properly. But I don't know where to match on to get the second group.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `\r` - [`– +([a-zA-Z0-9]*) +–|\r?\n(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/uH4nN3/1)?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion i need either a lookahead or lookbehind. So it matches into one capturing group. So something like: https://regex101.com/r/gK7pN8/3
It needs to match "Water" AND "Trainer" into 1 capturing group

Comment: @MarcWent: It is not possible with JavaScript regex engine since it does not support a branch reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** If newline is the faulty part, you can replace newline with \s+ in your pattern:

```
^(?:.*?)(?:\s*–\s*|\s+)(.*?)(?:\s*–\s*|$)
```

[**REGEX 101 DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/sV7nS6/1)

Comment: I need the capturing group under one number. So that in either case it is under $1, $2 or whatever group it is in.

Comment: Then please try version 1, the match is the first group.